# Выборка в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы, one и two:

- one: id(первич ключ), name, lastname, id_sale(внешний ключ)
- two: id_sale(первич ключ, привязан к таблице one), marka.

Таблица two привязана к таблице one внешнем ключом, пользователь регист в таблице one.
И как достать значение, например, второго столбца marka таблицы two?

**через PHP**

Comment: @Zow, не забывайте принимать верные ответы на ваши вопросы!

Comment: ок) я чет забыл совсем про это

Comment: Ну вот, опять забыл? xDDD

Comment: всмысле я забыл, я поставил

Comment: вот теперь - поставил :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
select `two`.`marka`
from `one`, `two`
where
  `one`.`id_sale` = `two`.`id_sale` and
  `one`.`lastname` = 'Чипполино'
```

Answer (score 0):

-> google -> sql join